# Real analysis problem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb R \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ be a function, and $ \lambda  \in (\frac {1}{2},1)$.

For all $ x,y \in \Bbb R$ we have

$$\lambda |x-f(x)| \leq |x-y| \Longrightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| \leq |x-y|.$$

Does any $\mu  \geq 1$ exist such that:
$$|x-f(y)| \leq  \mu |x-f(x)|+|x-y|\text{ ?}$$

Comment: Isn't this homework? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$|x-f(y)|=|(x-f(x))+(f(x)-f(y))|\leq |x-f(x)|+|f(x)-f(y)|.$$

Comment: How can I use this equation:$$\lambda|x−f(x)|\leq|x−y| \Longrightarrow |f(x)−f(y)|\leq|x−y|.$$